# How to subtract each item from a table ( sql server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The actual tables..

The top left is the assembly table

The top right is the items_table

the bottom left is the inventory table

[image: my tables]

[image: my keys]

I wanted to update the inventory based on the orders..

each product has multiple inventory items and I need to multiple each quantity in assembly_table by the quantity in items_table

Comment: In what order do you want to pair up the items? Any random order?

Comment: can u give more info about tables?

Comment: How do you know what the first row is?  (SQL tables are stored without order. `select * from table1` can legally return rows in different order each time you run it.)

Comment: @Andomar I am really new at sql... I didn't know sql did that.. but now that I know that I really don't know how to answer that question

Comment: Perhaps you could post the full table definitions.

Comment: What if the tables have different numbers of rows?

Comment: @user867621 post a screenshot of your database

Comment: I posted an example...Is that sufficient?

Comment: @user867621: It would also be useful if you described your data model. How are the tables related? Is there a one-to-one mapping between them? Are there any foreign keys defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join the tables together to multiply quantities with the same `product_tuid`:

```
select  a.product_tuid
,       a.quantity * i.quantity as QuantityProduct
from    assembly_table a
inner join
        items_table i
on      i.product_tuid= a.product_tuid
```

Comment: I just looked at it again... It was just ordered wrong.. now that I know how to fix.. thank you very much :)

Comment: Thank you again... I was working on a project and had to do another thing similar to this and I was able to do it on my own because I finally understood how you did what you did here